# Resize aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

I am over writing a standard 'new' button on a custom object with an aura component that references an LWC.
I am trying to resize the page but have not been successful.
This is what I thought would work but the page is still full screen.  Do I need to resize the LWC also?

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,lightning:actionOverride" access="global" >
    <aura:html tag="style">
        .slds-modal__container{
            max-width: 70rem !important;
            width:70% !important;
        }
    </aura:html>    
    <c:vAL_CreateLeasePaymentTerm></c:vAL_CreateLeasePaymentTerm>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: i dont see any modal class after overriding "new" if you want modal to come after you click on "new" you probably have to make that functionality too

Comment: Can you show the HTML of the LWC? Do you have any .slds-modal__container div there?